# Checking files if exists

Tags: shell

I found a code in this site on how to check if the file exists or not, and then added some code to match my idea. Am I doing this correct?

```
declare file="file.txt"
declare regex=$skedtemp
declare file_content=$( cat "${file}" )
if [[ " $file_content " =~ $regex ]] 
then
    skedran=$((RANDOM%200+600))
    skedtemp="SN$skedran"
    sked=$skedtemp
else
    sked=$skedtemp
fi
```

if it already exist then it will generate another random number and if it does not exist, the generated number will then be used.

Answer (score 1):

To test if files exists you can do this

```
[ -a file.txt ]
```

or

```
[ -e file.txt ]
```

or

```
[ -f file.txt ]
```

In response to [**Jonathan Leffler’s comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206996/checking-files-if-exists/14207130#comment19704182_14207130)

```
File operators:

  -a FILE        True if file exists.
```

[**ref**](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest)

Comment: Hmmm...OK, some different version of ... something.  `man test` sayeth '`EXPRESSION1 -a EXPRESSION2` _both EXPRESSION1 and EXPRESSION2 are true_'.  This was on RHEL5.  `man bash` does show the text you show.  However, it does not tell the whole story: `bash -c '[ -f file.txt -a ! -L file.txt ] && echo Yes || echo No'` has `-a` acting as an 'and' operator.  So, the `-a` operator appears to be ... err, polymorphic?  It seems odd to add yet another 'file exists' operator when there were already sufficient and the `-a` already had a meaning.  Weird!  But lots of stuff in `bash` seems odd to me.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler its akin to `[ $foo ]` and `[ -n $foo ]`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `grep`

```
file="file.txt"
if grep "$skedtemp" $file
then
    skedran=$((RANDOM%200+600))
    skedtemp="SN$skedran"
fi
sked=$skedtemp
```